# jhipster : gulp-inject is not injecting my new entity

Tags: gulp, jhipster

I am using jhipster v3.0.0

I have created an entity : yo jhipster:entity formation.
I havent changed gulpfile.js :

```
gulp.task('inject', function () {
   return gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.js').pipe(angularFilesort()), {relative: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));
});
```

then I run gulp.
Gulp tells me :

> gulp-inject 472 files into index.html.

But I can't find the related files (controller, state, etc.) in the index.html.

If someone can help me on this...

Comment: have you changed the index.html? In particular the special comment tags for inject:js ?

Comment: end tags were missing. thank you